# Board is not executing the program

Tags: stm32, arduino-ide

I am trying to program my stm32f103c6t6 with arduino ide via the st-link, after uploading the code successfully I got this

Sketch uses 12780 bytes (19%) of program storage space. Maximum is 65536 bytes.
Global variables use 2064 bytes (10%) of dynamic memory, leaving 18416 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 20480 bytes.
STM32 ST-LINK CLI v3.3.0.0
STM32 ST-LINK Command Line Interface

ST-LINK SN: 600016001600004C4732504E
ST-LINK Firmware version: V2J37S7 (Need Update)
Connected via SWD.
SWD Frequency = 4000K.
Target voltage = 3.3 V
Connection mode: Normal
Reset mode: Software reset
Device ID: 0x412
Device flash Size: 32 Kbytes
Device family: STM32F10xx Low-density

Loading file...
Flash Programming:
File : C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-55F6CCE1139B53A90BB0EB4482B23E16\Blink.ino.bin
Address : 0x08000000
Memory programming...
�������������������������������������������������� 0%
0%������ 12%������ 24%������ 36%������ 48%������ 60%������ 72%������ 84%������ 96%�� 100%
Memory programmed in 1s and 750ms.
Programming Complete.

MCU Reset.

Application started.

The problem is that the board is not executing the program which is blink built in LED

The board should execute the program if it was uploaded successfully

Comment: Please show your code and describe what board you have selected in the Arduino IDE. And also specify the exact brand and model of your STM32 board. The LED might be attached to a different pin than you expect.

Comment: the code is auto-generated by arduino IDE (File >> examples >> Basics >> Blink) , my board is stm32f1036t6 with built in led on pc 13

Comment: STM32F103C6T6 is the designation of the microcontroller, not the board designation. Many different development boards use it, e.g. https://stm32-base.org/boards/#stm32f1-boards. If your specific board isn't available in the Arduino IDE, or you have selected the wrong one, then likely the constant `LED_BUILTIN` will be incorrect. Replace `LED_BUILTIN` with the actual GPIO pin used for the LED on your specific board.

Comment: The built-in led is on GPIO PC13, I already replaced LED_BUILTIN with PC13 but I got the same problem